# Eager Initializing Connection Pool & Custom Timeout Value

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, tomcat-jdbc

I'm using the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool (which is the Spring Boot default) to manage connections to my PostgreSQL cluster, and I just noticed that the pool is created only when the very first query is made. My question is twofold:

1. Is there any elegant way to force the pool to be created eagerly (ie, when starting the application)? I believe that executing a simple query upon startup would do the trick, but I'd prefer a more elegant way if available.
2. During one of my tests I used `iptables` to drop all traffic directed at the PostgreSQL cluster. This caused the first query to last for about 127 seconds before failing with the message `Unable to create initial connections of pool`. 127 seconds is way too much. Is there any way I can set a lower value for the timeout? I've read the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) but could not conclude much.

Answer (score -1):

Well, for your first question, I can only think 2 methods:

- initSQL method of Tomcat Pool, which you already mentioned.
- Please see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html. Spring offer some mechanism to init DB & failfast. I think you can use this one.

For your second question; if you choose second approach for first question, than it'll automatically resolved. But you can always set

*spring.datasouce.max-wait*

parameter. In the Tomcat Pool doc it says

(int) The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before throwing an exception. Default value is 30000 (30 seconds)

but in your case, it's 127 seconds, which is strange..

Comment: That refers to DB initialization (schema creation and table population), not pool initialization. Also, providing `initSQL` does not, in any way, force the pool to be created eagerly.

Comment: I know, but to init db, you can use any kind of sql statement, and this require underlying pool created & initialized